# how to share environment variables between react app and express js server hosting it as static site

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react app hosted as static site under express server project in a folder called client/build. I have some oauth redirect uris that point to express server also points to for token retrieval later. My react-app redirects user to oauth endpoint which my express server env variables also refer to.

```
    ` //express .env :
      process.env.HOST=localhost
      process.env.PORT=port
      process.env.OAUTH2URI=example.com
     `
   ` //react .env :
      process.env.REACT_APP_HOST=localhost
      process.env.REACT_APP_PORT=port
      process.env.REACT_APP_OAUTH2URI=example.com
     `
```

when i run my express app, how can the react app refer to the same host and port my express server app is using ?

Can i not refer the common env variables from express app into react app without duplicating with different names.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of things, of which none seemed to work.
What I did as a workaround for this is make an API in Express which will be called by the front-end and will forward the env vars.
Something of the sort:

```
app.get('/getEnvironmentVars', (_, res) => {
    res.json({ ENVIRONMENT: process.env })
})
```

Then you just fetch it in the front-end code like:

```
export async function getEnvironmentVarsFromExpress() {
    return await fetch('/getEnvironmentVars').then((res) => res.json())
}
```

Comment: is this safe though? what if someone looked at the network traffic on your website and replicated your request to `/getEnvironmentVars`?

Comment: It would be safe, as the environment variables used for the client-side would be publicly accessible if used ordinarily anyways.

Answer (score 0):

so when I was looking at passing environment variables to React today, I happened across this website https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ which says that all enviroment variables used by React have to start with REACT_APP for security reasons.

Comment: That is true but doesn't seem to be influenced by setting the environment variable in .env of the express app